# Do I avoid becoming dependent and desensitized to stimulants or interpolating caffeine and yohimbine?

Tags: pre-workout, caffeine

I don't know exactly how the both act on the organism. I just know that the effects are pretty much the same and that both causes dependency on prolonged use. Can I avoid becoming dependent or desensitized if I interpolate caffein and yohimbine?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because pharmacodynamics with no relation to fitness or exercise is off topic.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov This has direct effect on exercise performance, so obviously it is related to fitness. Otherwise, where am I supposed to ask it?

Comment: Your question is how to avoid chemical dependance, so not a fitness question.